# What is OpenID "Automatic Login"?

Tags: api, authentication, openid

What is OpenID "Automatic Login"?

I've never heard this term in a technical sense until today. It has suddenly appeared in Facebook's marketing blog in reference to their new deal with Google.

To be clear, they assert that virtually no other OpenID providers besides Google implement OpenID "Automatic Login", thus no other OpenIDs are currently supported by Facebook.

Does this even exist?

FYI, yes this is a programming question.  I would really love to see the ***API documentation*** for this feature.  Please post a link to it if you are familiar with it.  Thanks!!

Facebook announcement:
http://www.insidefacebook.com/2009/05/18/facebook-launches-openid-support-users-can-now-login-with-a-gmail-account/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that this is just an application of OpenID's "Immediate mode":

Immediate mode allows you to attempt to verify the user without them leaving your site at all. This is normally possible if, during the first time you attempt to verify a user, they choose to always allow you to verify them and offers a slightly more streamlined login experience.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I am investigating now to try to confirm this is what Google and Facebook are using.

Comment: Yes, this is in the spec: 9.3 Immediate requests, and Google documents it as Immediate Mode.  The Facebook wording of "automatic login" confused me, and I was not able to find any information when searching on that phrase.

Comment: Right.  This is just checkid_immediate, and is in fact what Facebook is using.  Nothing special on the Google side of things and many Providers support this very ordinary part of OpenID.  It's just that many RPs don't leverage it.

Answer (score 4):

The reason people are excited about this is that it is a much smoother User Interface experience than using just OpenID.

The new system was first demonstrated by Plaxo developers and now has additional information available, see http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html

A blog post from TechCrunch: http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/google_openid_updates_ui.php

The issue right now, afaik, is that the methodology is poorly documented, so it is mostly appearing on sites that are paying JanRain corp. for their implementation.

Comment: So this is an extension Google wrote on their own, and are now contributing it to the OpenID standard?  I'm still confused as to why *no* other providers are using this yet.

Comment: Or I should phrase that differently. How can one tell what providers are supporting this?

Comment: It does work with other providers, see the JanRain product offering details. Google is being helpful in supplying info about it and a demo program. Here's a msg that helped me understand what the advance was: http://groups.google.com/group/google-federated-login-api/browse_thread/thread/eeecf76d23f96241/85d1036ccbbcdf03

Comment: Thanks. (+1 earlier) I realize now it works with other providers.  I think what Facebook is saying is they will only support specific top-tier providers, and Google is the only one of those they have already collaborated with to launch OpenID.  Again, thanks.

Comment: The blog posts are all misleading.  Google is offering NO special functionality here.  It's straight, pure OpenID.  Most OpenID Providers support the same functionality, and Facebook allows auto-login from more than just Google Providers.  Hook up your own Myopenid or other OpenID with a Provider, log in once using "Trust this site" at the OP, and you get auto-login from that OP as well.